# How to hide an empty databound DropDownList

Tags: c#, hide, dropdown, databound

I have a databound DropDownList and I need a code that will only show the DropDownList if there is a value in the Database, if the there is no value/empty DropDownlist it should not be visible.

I tried:

```html
   if (ddlFruits.Items.Count == 1)
     {
         ddlFruits.Visible = false;
     }
     else
     {
         ddlFruits.Visible = true;

     }
```

Comment: So, ```myDropDown.Visible = myDropDown.Items.Count>0``` ?

Comment: Check my answer and tell me if helped you

Comment: unfortunately, it does not. It hides the dropdownlist completely

Comment: @JanaPasch that means you don't have any items in it. You should write this line in render of your page-> after you load the items in the dropdown.

Comment: @JanaPasch *It hides the dropdownlist completely*... but that's what you asked for: *if the there is no value/empty DropDownlist it should not be visible*.

Answer (score 0):

```
ddlFruits.Visible = ddlFruits.Items.Count > 0
```

Comment: ahaha. But not, you are was a first.. :)